# Alimentar campos na view pela controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho utilizado uma forma de carregar campos na view da seguinte forma: Faço um método retornando um JSon na controller, aí crio uma função JQuery que pega esse retorno e alimento os campos da view, no sucesso do ajax. Bem, essa foi uma abordage,m que eu aprendi quando trabalhei com e-commerce. A pergunta então é a seguinte. Essa abordagem está entre as melhores práticas? Hoje tenho um formulário com 4 abas. Como faria então usando essa abordagem? Há outra forma melhor e mais elegante?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, via Javascript você alimenta os campos do HTML.
Você pode fazer um HTML separado para cada retorno, e somente substituir o HTML inteiro.
Isso evita ter que deixar muita lógica no Javascript.

No controller, você direciona para o HTML com os dados prontos para mostrar, e no javascript só substitui uma "div" inteira, por exemplo.

Comment: Nesse caso eu não necessito de html dinâmico como eu venho fazendo. Logo eu substituiria apenas os Textbox que receberiam valores, certo? Não preciso estar criando html dinâmicos, certo?

Comment: Sim. Você pode deixar o HTML estático.